# keyboardType (name-phone-pad) - React Native

Tags: react-native

name-phone-pad keyboard type does not work in react native for ios.

```
<TextInput
          autoCapitalize="characters"
          maxLength={4}
          minLength={3}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={mosOutput => this.setState({ mosInput: mosOutput })}
          value={this.state.mosInput}
          keyboardType={'name-phone-pad'}
        />
```

This shows default keyboard. Am I missing something?

Comment: is it supported on ios, did you check the docs ?

Comment: yes, it is supported.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype

Comment: just curios, can you remove the {} and just write "name-phone-pad",

Comment: same result... didn't work :/

Comment: your running this on a simulator ? , did you try to run on a real device ?

Comment: i am using a real device, no simulator.

Comment: Fellas, it should look like a normal keyboard (go to their docs and run it). What kind of keyboard do you need?

Comment: read their docs, they link this to see screenshots of the keyboards -> https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/

i want the keyboard of the screenshot they linked to the name-phone-pad in ios.